# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException and java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, classnotfoundexception, noclassdeffounderror

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~7KBUn2lwEDhEAtW_Isu_oA==/com.valentindiring.xx-scZlLvqEbNpegW1x47tPtw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~7KBUn2lwEDhEAtW_Isu_oA==/com.valentindiring.xx-scZlLvqEbNpegW1x47tPtw==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]


java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/location/LocationServices;                                                                                                    at lib.valentindiring.threeprojectscomposelibrary.screens.settings.AreaContentKt.AreaContentAfterLoadingBottomSheet(AreaContent.kt:387)
```

I had deinstalled the app, then clean task, rebuild.
But it didn't help.

In the threeprojectscomposelibrary test app module it works!
But not in the production app.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the resolution.
transitive dependency!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).